# How to retrieve a count number of specified values in mysql (even if no records)?

Tags: mysql

Suppose I have a table with a field named 'rating', it may take different values, but I want to receive a count of specific values.

Example:

```
Create table mytable(
    rating int(1),
);
```

First and the obvious way I could think of was the following:

```
select rating,count(rating) from mytable group by rating order by rating
```

The problem though it is not clear how many values it would return, it may be also not easy to process them way.

What I would really like to do is to select two fields in one row showing the number of records that have some specific values.

Example...

```
//something like this (some pseudocode):

select count(rating=-1) as rating1, count (rating=1) as rating2 from mytable
```

Could you advice on some neat way I could select in the ^ above format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select SUM(IF(rating=-1,1,0)) AS rating1, 
   SUM(IF(rating=1,1,0)) AS rating2 from mytable
```

Comment: even shorter: `select SUM(rating=-1) AS rating1, SUM(rating=1) AS rating2 from mytable`

Comment: I may probably also add ifnull, if no records: `select ifnull(SUM(rating=-1),0) AS rating1, ifnull(SUM(rating=1),0) AS rating2 from mytable`